# Data not getting inserted after , in php

Tags: php

My data is not fully getting inserted into database

```
function()
{
    $a='abcd(a,b,c,d,e)';
    $sql="Insert into tablename(fieldname) Values('".$a."')";
    $res=mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Value is getting into the database but not fully i.e `abcd(a.`

Comment: so you want to insert abcd(a,b,c,d,e) into one column? try escaping the string?

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: What is the type of your column ? You must have something like varchar(6), where 6 is the maximum length of the string. Increase it.

Comment: That code shouldn't give that result (OlivierH has identified a way that it could, but the code still appears to be very placeholdery so the rest of this comment still applies). Have you produced a simplified test case and not confirmed that it still demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The column in your datase is not large enough to hold the data you are trying to insert.

You would probably have noticed this if you had included the structure in your question (hint, next time do incllude the structure).